# Limit in number of bibliographies using multibbl

Tags: bibliographies

Wondering whether there is a limit in the number of bibliographies one can create while using the package `multibbl`.  I have  been able to create 12 but the moment I try to create the 13 I seem to have issues. The error I get is

> ```
> No room for a new \write.\e@ch@ck ...message {No room for a new \string #4}\fi \fi \newbibliography{workshops}
> ```

12 seems like an odd number. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{morewrites}`.

Comment: Since you are not using `biblatex`, but the `multibbl` package I have retagged your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn, that worked.  Obviously there were additional streams and with the extra bibliography I exceeded the limit of 16 (number that seems logical).

Comment: @JuanAntonio I think we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed... It can be closed. Thanks for your help.